# VBA not recognizing MsgBox property VbMsgBoxStyle

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm getting the error message "Compile Error: Named argument not found," when I try to run my VBA code. VBA doesn't seem to recognize the last property `VbMsgBoxStyle`.

```
Dim dump As VbMsgBoxResult
dump = VBA.Interaction.MsgBox _
       Title:="Invalid Scope!", _
       Prompt:="You entered Invalid Scope !!!", _
       VbMsgBoxStyle:=vbCritical
```

On the other hand my Object Browser shows this for MsgBox:

```
Function MsgBox(Prompt, [Buttons As VbMsgBoxStyle = vbOKOnly], [Title], [HelpFile], [Context]) As VbMsgBoxResult
    Member of VBA.Interaction
```

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property is `Buttons` not `vbMsgBoxStyle`.  Your code should read like this:

```
VBA.Interaction.MsgBox _
            Title:="Invalid Scope!", _
            Prompt:="You entered Invalid Scope !!!", _
            Buttons:=vbCritical
```

Comment: Now I feel dumb.  The answer was even on my screen Thanks